# Import statsmodel has no attribute score_test_proportions_2indep

Tags: python, statsmodels

I tried below all 3 codes however it return error as following. Please advise

`Module 'statsmodels.stats.proportion' has no attribute 'score_test_proportions_2indep'`

Link to documentation : [statsmodels.stats.proportion.score_test_proportions_2indep](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.score_test_proportions_2indep.html)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.stats.proportion.score_test_proportions_2indep()
```

```
import statsmodels as sm
sm.stats.proportion.score_test_proportions_2indep()
```

```
from statsmodels.stats import proportion
proportion.score_test_proportions_2indep()
```

Python version as following `3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 9 2017, 00:19:18)`  not sure if this is correctly extracted.

Comment: ```from statsmodels.stats import proportion
proportion.score_test_proportions_2indep()``` seems to work on my side.Can you check you version you are using?

Comment: 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  9 2017, 00:19:18) . Hi, as above. Thanks

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Do you mean python or statsmodels version? How do i find statsmodel version? i am using jupyter notebook from coursera course

Comment: `import statsmodels; statsmodels.__version__`

Comment: Thanks, the statsmodel is '0.9.0'. so it guess it is due to old version cause the website now mentioned "statsmodels v0.12.2"

Comment: @mmrbulbul how did you figure out from [this page](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.test_proportions_2indep.html) that, thats how you are supposed to write the from import statement.